# Count in aggregate subquery or join

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have two tables that define game details: a table with the games and a table with moves.

I can tell who's turn it is by

```
SELECT (COUNT(idx) %2) FROM history WHERE gameID=x
```

on result=1 it's white and result=0 for black.

Now I want to select a particular series of games, where it is my move.

It is not known if I am white or black in a game.

So now I use another query for the game:

```
SELECT g.gameID 
FROM games AS g
WHERE (g.whitePlayer = 2 or (g.blackPlayer = 2)
```

Then I use the gameID to see if it's my move. If not, then I skip that game.

I would like to combine these two, I tried to make an aggregate subset but unsuccessfully because of the `COUNT()`

For example this does not work and returns nothing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM games as g 
WHERE (g.whitePlayer = 2) 
  AND gameID IN (SELECT gameID 
                 FROM history as h 
                 HAVING (COUNT(h.idx) %2) = 1)
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(h.idx)
FROM history as h
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT gameID
     FROM games 
     WHERE (whitePlayer = 2)) As thesegames ON h.gameID = thesegames.gameID 
HAVING (COUNT(h.idx) %2) = 1
```

Does anybody have a clue on how to solve this?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/425fb

Comment: Please remember that *auto_increment* are only guaranteed to be unique in the table. There is not guarantee for them to be sequentially ordered, nor never reused. This is especially true if you have to deal with rollbacks on transactional tables: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d39c/1. Not mentioning concurrent inserts in your DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am not quite finished but this answers my own question

```
SELECT g.gameID, (count(h.idx)%2) as lastmove
FROM games as g
  inner join history as h on g.gameID=h.gameID 
WHERE (g.whitePlayer=2)
GROUP by g.gameID, g.whitePlayer
HAVING (g.whitePlayer=2 AND lastmove=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Select count(h.idx) , COUNT(h.idx) %2 
 From history as h
 Inner Join  games g
 On h.gameID = g.gameID 
 WHERE  whitePlayer=2
 HAVING  COUNT(h.idx) %2 = 1
```

Comment: closer, but the first count returns all counted items where whiteplayer=2. I need all games. If you would do SELECT h.gameID, etc.. this would return only the first appropriate game.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle and your wished result ?

Comment: Need all gameID's from games where it's my move.

Comment: Aha, i did not understand yesterday but you meant a sqlfiddle ! I created one at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/425fb/3/0